# How to call a webelement from one class to another class in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a class 'Registration.java' where i defined a web element as like below:

```
WebElement regForm = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/form"));
List<WebElement> inputFields = regForm.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='form-con']/input"));
```

Another class 'Validations.java':

```
List<WebElement> errors = **regForm**.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='error-container']/small"));
for(int i = 0; i < inputFields.size(); i++){
    **inputFields**.get(i).sendKeys("");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='signin-con']/input")).click(); }
```

In the above example, 'Registration.java' class has web element objects 'regForm' and 'inputFields'. I don't want to define again same in the second class. So, those web elements want to use in the another class 'Validations.java'. But, Java program is showing error 'object cannot be resolved' in the second class. How can I call those webelements without re-defining again?

Comment: If you do not want to define again and again then define that variable as static out of main method at top.`public static WebElement regform`

Comment: It works by defining public static variable .

Comment: Cheers :) Happy to help you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use getters and setters or public static variables to resolve the problem

***Using Getters***

you can create getters and setters for the variables in the Registration.java fie as below.

```
private WebElement regForm;
private List<WebElement> inputFields;

public WebElement getRegForm(){
     regForm = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/form"));
     return regForm;
}

 public List<WebElement> getInputFields(){
     inputFields = regForm.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='form-con']/input"));
}
```

And from the Validations.java file you need to call the respective getters.

```
Registration registration = new Registration();
WebElement regForm = registration.getRegForm();
```

***Using global static variables***

You can define the variables in Registration.java as public static :

```
public static WebElement regForm = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/form"));
public static List<WebElement> inputFields = regForm.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='form-con']/input"));
```

And access them in other classes as :

```
WebElement regForm = Registration.regForm;
```

The first option is the best way to handle this kind of stuff. But 2nd option works too.
As learning process I think you should really look at the page object pattern in Selenium. That will help you a lot. There is a nice tutorial on that in tutorialspoint. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/selenium/selenium_page_object_model.htm

Comment: Both methods works a lot. Good suggestion to use page objects. I'll follow it also.

Comment: Using public static variable, error got resolved. But when run the program which throws a NullPointerException. Error shows in the second class. I think webElement is having null value. My question is, we're referring value from the first value. How could it be null value here?

Comment: Please post the code where you are getting the exception

Comment: Validations()
{
List<WebElement> errors = regForm.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='error-container']/small"));
System.out.println("No. of Errors: " + errors.size());
 }

Comment: You have to reference the regForm variable through the Registration class. `List<WebElement> errors = Registration.regForm.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='error-container']/small")); `

Comment: yes. i did reference as WebElement regForm = Registration.regForm; on top of it.

Comment: By mistake, Did initialization twice in the first class. `public static WebElement regForm; 
WebElement regForm = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/form"));`
 It works now. By removing WebElement from the second line. 

`public static WebElement regForm; regForm = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/form"));`

Answer (score 0):

I like to have my webelements for every webpage in a separate class file in a folder 'PageElements',
having also a 'Pages' folder with classes for every webpage which use the PageElements classes (the static import is key here),
as also a 'Tests' folder with test classes which communicate with the Pages classes.

Here's a sample Page object model structure with Selenium and NUnit in C#:

***LoginPageElements.cs***

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
namespace MyNamespace.PageElements
{
    internal class LoginPageElements
    {
        public static IWebDriver _driver;       
        public LoginPageElements(IWebDriver driver)
        {   _driver = driver;   }

        internal static IWebElement _inputTxt_AccountName
        { get => _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type='text'][placeholder='Trading Account/Email'][name='AccountName']")); }
        internal static IWebElement _inputTxt_Password
        { get => _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type='password'][placeholder='Password'][name='Password']")); }
        internal static IWebElement _btn_LoginSubmit
        { get => _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type='Submit'][name='LoginSubmit']")); }
        internal static IWebElement _labelBtn_Logout
        { get => _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span[class='headerLogout logout']")); }                                                    
    }
}
```

***LoginPage.cs***

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using MyNamespace.PageElements;
using static MyNamespace.PageElements.LoginPageElements;
namespace MyNamespace.Pages
{
    internal class LoginPage
    {
        private IWebDriver _driver;
        private User _user;
        public LoginPage(IWebDriver driver, User user)
        {
            _driver = driver;
            _user = user;
            new LoginPageElements(_driver);
        }
        public void LoadPage()
        {
            _driver.Url = "https://www.samplepage.com/";
        }

        public void DoLoginAndLogout()
        {
            _inputTxt_AccountName.SendKeys(_user.Username);
            _inputTxt_Password.SendKeys(_user.Password);
            _btn_LoginSubmit.Click();
            _labelBtn_Logout.Click();
        }
    }
}
```

***LoginTest.cs***

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using MyNamespace.Pages;
using MyNamespace.NonPageObjects;
namespace MyNamespace.Tests
{
    internal class RegisterLoginTest
    {
        private IWebDriver _driver;
        private User _user = new User(); //User is part of NonPageObjects 

        [SetUp]
        public void Init()
        {   _driver = new ChromeDriver();   }

        [Test]
        public void LoggingWithRealAccount_Positive_01()
        {
            LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(_driver, _user);
            loginPage.LoadPage();
            loginPage.DoLoginAndLogout();
        }


        [TearDown]
        public void Cleanup()
        {   _driver.Quit(); }
    }
}
```